# Determine dependant rows of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Given a matrix, I define the following equivalence relation on the set of its rows : two rows are equivalent if they are colinear.

I am interested in the following algorithm : determine the set of equivalence classes for this equivalence relation (as fast as possible ;-)) in the two following cases :

1. the case of a general square matrix
2. the case of a general non-square matrix

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no faster algorithm than constructing the equivalence classes one by one, ie. for every row check, if there is equivalence class where it belongs, if not - create one.

Time complexity in this case is $O(n^2)$

Comment: Nothing better than row-elimination method or than QR, then ?